# Can we affect the standard Lightning Email feature on Case with code?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

Rather not code this from scratch. My question is specific to how I can tap into Lightning Experience's existing functionality. Just as an example, is there a way to leverage a '[marker interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:actionOverride/documentation)' to add code to existing Lightning Email on Case?

On Case, there's the standard Lightning Email we all know and love. There is now a Quick Text feature (see speech bubble icon in image below) that allows the user to insert text into the Email body.

I need similar but more complex...
- User should be able to pick from a List of a CustomObject.
- Their selection should do 2 things
   - insert text into the Subject and Body fields
   - insert email addresses into To/CC/From/BCC as designated in the selected CustomObject record
   - update fields on the Case as designated in the CusotmObject record

[image: Existing Lightning Experience - Email action on Case]